# Wirte information from txt-files to xls with an identifier

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an excel sheet with the columns

```
IdNr    Filename rep_cke file_description
10      5432.txt rutine  "information from txt file (5432.txt)"
20      5683.txt rutine  "information from txt file (5683.txt)"
```

Now is there a way to use python to write the all the information from the text-files to the corresponding cell for the matching filename in the sheet?
 what i've come to so fare

```
   def main():
    file = open("51712640_Rutine.txt", "r")
    lines = file.readlines()
    file.close()
    print("Txt file read")
    #print(lines)


main()

csv_file = open("bakgrunnsData.csv")
csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=";")

for row in csv_reader:
    print (row[1])

csv_file.close()
```

Comment: Of course there is. Have you attempted it yourself?

Comment: I've tried reading throu the txt-file, makeing list of bits and writeing that to a spread sheet. that only seems to overwrite everthing else

Comment: would be really nice with some tips to get going :)

Comment: @Jørgen Even if it's not working, you should provide your code attempt so we can see what you tried and help you from that. See [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Python has a built in `csv` module. If you can convert your `xls` file to `csv`, this should be good enough.

Alternatively, you can use the `pandas` library for more advanced functionality.